# Mover filas de una lista de listas hacia abajo

Tags: java, netbeans

Quisiera ayuda con esto,tengo una lista de listas, y quiero que todas las filas bajen una posición para que la última fila tome la primera posición

Pero en vez de eso la fila con &(la ultima) va subiendo, cuando la idea es que debe ser añadida una vez que todas las demás bajaron.

La listas tiene una tamaño de 8x84

```
 public void MoverAbajo()
{
    Object x=banner.get(banner.length()-1);
    //for(int s = 0; s<80; s++){
      for( int i=banner.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
         if(i==0){
          banner.remove(i);banner.toString();
         }
         else{
          Object l=banner.get(i-1);   
          banner.remove(i-1);

          banner.add(i,l);
          Imprimir();
         } 

        }
```

}

```
 public void add(int index, Object o) {
   if (index < 0 || index > size) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("add : " + index + "< 0 || " + index + ">" + size);
    }
    if (isEmpty()) { // LISTA VACIA
        lista[index] = o;
    } else if (index == 0) { // INSERTAR AL INICIO

        lista[index] = o;
    } else if (index == size) { //INSERTAR AL FINAL
        lista[index] = o;
    } else { // INSERTAR POR EL MEDIO
        moveR(index);
        lista[index] = o;
    }

    size++;
    }


public void remove(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > (size - 1)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("remove : " + index + "< 0 || " + index + ">" + (size - 1));
    }
    if (index == 0) { //ELIMINA AL INICIO
        moveL(index);
    } else if (index == size - 1) { /* ELIMINA AL FINAL - NO HACE NADA POR EL SIZE-- */ } else { //ELIMINA POR EL MEDIO
        moveL(index);
    }
    size--;
}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes. Creo que tu código es incompleto. Para poder ayudarte sería mejor que completarás el código.

Answer (score 0):

**Interpreto** que lo que quieres implentar es una **LISTA CIRCULAR FINITA**.
En base a eso te propongo esta solución:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ListaCircularFinita {

    //Inicializamos la lista de listas
    private Object[] lista; 
    private int size;

    public ListaCircularFinita(int filas) {
        lista = new Object[filas];
        size = filas;
        for (int i=0;i<filas;i++) {
            lista[i] = new String("fila" + i); 
        }
    }

    public void add(int index, Object o) {
        if (index < 0 || index > size) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("add : " + index + "< 0 || " + index + ">" + size);
            }
        if (isEmpty()) { // LISTA VACIA
            lista[index] = o;
        } 
        else if (index == 0) { // INSERTAR AL INICIO
            lista[index] = o;
        } else if (index == (size-1)) { //INSERTAR AL FINAL
            lista[index] = o;
            } else { // INSERTAR POR EL MEDIO
                moveR(index);
                lista[index] = o;
                }
        //size++;
    }

    public void printLista() {
        for (int i=0;i<lista.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i + ". " + lista[i].toString());
        }
    }
    private void moveR(int index) {
        Object last = lista[lista.length-1];
        for (int i=lista.length-1;i>index;i--)
        {
            lista[i] = lista[i-1];
        }
        lista[0] = last;
    }

    private boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return size==0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ListaCircularFinita lc = new ListaCircularFinita(8);

        lc.printLista();
        String[] l = {"1","2","3"}; 
        lc.add(5, Arrays.toString(l));
        lc.printLista();
        String[] l2 = {"1","2","3","4","5"}; 
        lc.add(5, Arrays.toString(l2));
        lc.printLista();
    }

}
```